# Is the code of ZMCSCG channel like this ? h_1=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));

Tags: matlab

We represent by h_K is N by 1 matrix,the channel vector between the N-antenna TX and the single-antenna RX k . The entries of each h_k are assumed to be independent Zero-Mean Circularly Symmetric Complex Gaussian (ZMCSCG) random variables with variance σ^2_{h,k} that depends on the propagation losses of the TX to RX k.

The range if k is 1~4,
Can i just write the code like this ? or what should i improve?

```
h_1=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_2=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_3=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_4=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_kk=cat(2,h_1 ,h_2 ,h_3, h_4)
```

h_kk is the ZMCSCG

Comment: `h_kk=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(N,4)+1i*randn(N,4));` ?

Comment: @SardarUsama but if that is true,what is the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: the above code generates the four samples h_1 ... h_4 directly and makes it unecessary to cat them afterwards

Comment: You're generating `h_kk` with 8 calls to `randn`, 4 calls to `sqrt,` and 1 call to `cat` and creating 4 unnecessary variables. This is inefficient

Comment: Your channels all have variance 1, however, you were asked to make them variance \sigma_{h,k}^2. You're missing this part.

Comment: @Florian so i should rewrite to h_1=sqrt(\sigma_{h,k}^2/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));?

Answer (score 0):

To account for the desired variance in your channels, you would need to either do this:

```
h_1=sqrt(sigmah1squared/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_2=sqrt(sigmah2squared/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_3=sqrt(sigmah3squared/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_4=sqrt(sigmah4squared/2)*(randn(N,1)+1i*randn(N,1));
h_kk = [h1, h2, h3, h4];
```

or more compactly

```
sigmasquared = [sigmah1squared, sigmah2squared, sigmah3squared, sigmah4squared];
h_kk = sqrt(sigmasquared/2)*(randn(N,4)+1i*randn(N,4));
```